# Diagonalizability properties

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Say matrices X and Y are both diagonalisable and they have the same set of eigenvalues. Each of the eigenvalues have the same algebraic and geometry multiplicities. From here, I can see that the Tr(X) and Tr(Y) are equal and same goes with their determinants since their eigenvalues are the same. But what does it say about their eigenspaces? Are the eigenspaces of both matrices X and Y similar with respect to each eigenvalue by that i mean for every E<sub>$\lambda$</sub>, E<sub>$\lambda$</sub>(X)=E<sub>$\lambda$</sub>(Y) . Are these equal? The det(X-$\lambda$I) and det(Y - $\lambda$I) are both equal as well right? It seems pretty simple but i cant seem to get it.

Comment: What does it mean for eigenspaces to be “similar with respect to each eigenvalue”? If by $\det(A-\lambda I)$ you mean the characteristic polynomial, that is completely determined by the eigenvalues and their multiplicities, so similarity implies same characteristic polynomial (but not conversely).

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ have the same set of eigenvalues with the same corresponding algebraic multiplicities (regardless of the geometric multiplicities), then their characteristic polynomials will be identical. If it is also known that the geometric multiplicities are the same, then there exists an invertible transformation between each eigenspace of $X$ and the corresponding eigenspace of $Y$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have made an edit in my post, thats what i meant by the eigenspaces are equal or not. By the way i understand it although they have same eigenvalues, the two matrices are different which may correspond to different spans of eigenvectors for both X and Y. Am i getting a wrong concept of this?

Comment: No, the eigenspaces need not be identical. For a trivial example, take $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&2\end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\0&1\end{array}\right)$. The eigenspace of $1$ for $A$ is $\{(x,0)\mid x\in\mathbb{F}\}$,. and for $B$ is $\{(0,y)\mid y\in\mathbb{F}\}$.

Comment: You have $X$ and $Y$, and $A$ and $B$. Which is it?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry i have made a mistake and corrected it and thank you i see it now. However the characteristic polynomials, trace and determinant of both matrices are equal am i right?

Comment: The trace and characteristic polynomials are completely determined by the eigenvalues and their algebraic multiplicities over an algebraically closed field; if $A$ and $B$ have those equal, *even if they are not similar*, then they will have the same trace, the same determinant, and the same characteristic polynomial.